# If an algebra $A$ belongs to a variety and $\phi$ is a homomorphism then is $\phi(A)$ in the variety?

Tags: abstract-algebra, universal-algebra

My attempt: Let $A$ be an algebra that belongs to variety $V$ and $\phi$ be a homomorphism $\phi: A \rightarrow B$.  Then for any term $t(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$ and any elements $a_1,a_2,...a_n \in A$, we have  $\phi(t(a_1,a_2,...a_n )) = t(\phi(a_1), \phi(a_2),...\phi(a_n))$.  Where do I go from here?

Comment: Do you see what you need to show to get that $\phi(A)$ is a variety? Can you do this if $V$ was, say, the variety of all groups (or monoids or semigroups - that is, if the variety has a straightforward and fixed stucture)?

Comment: @MiloBrandt Honestly no.  This is the first lecture on varietys and the like.  I know that an algebra $B$ belongs to the variety if it satisfies all the identities of the variety, but I'm not even sure what those would be in this case

Comment: @MiloBrandt Could you please give me a hint?  I have been stuck for hours

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is a variety $V$? It's a set of algebras defined by a set of equations. How do we show that $\phi(A)\in V$? We show it satisfies all the equations defining $V$.

So suppose $t(x_1,\dots,x_n) = t'(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ is one of these equations. To show that $\phi(A)$ satisfies this equation, we need to show that for any $b_1,\dots,b_n\in \phi(A)$, $t(b_1,\dots,b_n) = t'(b_1,\dots,b_n)$.

*Hint:* For each $b_i$, pick a preimage $a_i$ in $A$, and use the fact that $A$ satisfies the equation, together with the relationship between homomorphisms and terms that you wrote down in the question.

Comment: You would also need to define what the operations on the set $\phi(A)$ are.  The natural choice would be to inherit the operations from $B$ - but for that to work, you need to verify that $\phi(A)$ is closed under all these operations.

Comment: @DanielSchepler If $\phi\colon A\to B$ is a homomorphism of algebras, then $\phi(A)$ is automatically a subalgebra.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Since the question asks "is $\phi(A)$ in the variety?", and not "can the set $\phi(A)$ be equipped with the structure of an algebra in such a way that it is in the variety?", I'm assuming that the OP already knows that $\phi(A)$ is a subalgebra of $B$ and that the notation $\phi(A)$ refers to this subalgebra, and not just to its underlying set.

Comment: And once you know that $\phi(A)$ is a subalgebra of $B$, you could also inherit the relations from $B$.  So IMO showing $\phi(A)$ is a subalgebra is the most important part - even if it *is* easy as egreg says.  (Still, the argument given here would be useful for constructing a quotient of $A$ by a congruence, i.e. a subset of $A \times A$ which is both a subalgebra and an equivalence relation, and showing that quotient belongs to the variety.)

Comment: @DanielSchepler I totally agree that defining the structure on $\phi(A)$ is important. My point is that the question doesn't even make sense until the structure on $\phi(A)$ is defined, so I thought it was safe to assume that this definition (and the verification that it makes sense) was in the background of the question. Note also that we're not assuming that $B$ is in $V$, so you can't conclude that $\phi(A)$ is in $V$ just because it's a substructure of $B$.

Comment: OK, I guess I missed that part.

Comment: @AlexKruckman So is this the answer you are trying to lead me to?  Let $b_1,...,b_n \in \phi(A)$ and $t(b_1,...,b_n) = t'(b_1,...,b_n)$.  Then let $a_i$ be the preimage of $b_i \forall i$.  Then $t(b_1,...,b_n) = t(\phi(a_i),...,\phi(a_n)) = \phi(t(a_1,...,a_n))$ and similarly $t'(b_1,...,b_n)  = \phi(t'(a_1,...,a_n))$ so the equality is satisfied.  I'm not sure at all if that last part is right

Comment: @DanielSchepler Does the solution I gave in my last comment look right to you?

Comment: @user558377 Yes, that's correct. But you should make sure you understand why the last part is right!

Comment: @AlexKruckman Thanks.  I just wasn't sure if it was sufficient to conclude $\phi(A) \in V$, but I get why the equations can be manipulated in that way

Comment: @user558377 Just one minor point: in general, preimages aren't going to be unique, so you should say "let $a_i$ be *a* preimage of $b_i$ for each $i$" - "*a* preimage" instead of "*the* preimage".  (Note since this is only a finite number of choices, you wouldn't need the axiom of choice for this step.)